# Reading data from a text file and populate a list using a 1-liner

Tags: python, optimization, text-files

For solving Project Euler's [problem#67](http://projecteuler.net/problem=67), i used below code to [read data](https://projecteuler.net/project/triangle.txt) & load data in the initial list, D.

I am wondering if all these can be done in Pythonic 1-liner

```
f=open("triangle.txt")
A=[]
for i in range(100):
    A.append((f.readline()).strip())

// init 
D=[]
for i in range(100):
    D.append((A[i]).split())
for i in range(100):
        for j in range(len(D[i])):
            D[i][j]= int(D[i][j])
```

Whereas, the data format is like this:

```
59
73 41
52 40 09
26 53 06 34
10 51 87 86 81
61 95 66 57 25 68
...................
.....................
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by using a list comprehension (Python 2 or 3):

```
with open('triangle.txt') as infh:
    D = [[int(w) for w in line.split()] for line in infh]
```

or, if using Python 2, using `map()`:

```
with open('triangle.txt') as infh:
    D = [map(int, line.split()) for line in infh]
```

`map()` in Python 3 returns an iterator; in Python 2 it returns a list and would be faster for this usecase.

Comment: @kmonsoor: That's the point; the first line works in both Python 2 and 3, but the latter is faster in Python 2.

Comment: @martjin: i see ... thanks for great answer. would u mind to change "inf" to "f" as, IMO, f is more popular as file_handler, like i for indexing ...? :)

Comment: @kmonsoor: Does it matter that much? I use `infh` and `outfh` a lot, just forgot to type the extra `f`. For anything but loop counters, I prefer to use longer names.